# не переопределяется mounted

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Есть 2 компонента Vue. Один наследуется от другого. В первом (базовом) есть такой mounted:

```
protected async mounted(): Promise<void> {
    const tab: any = this.getTabByName("basic-data");
    const organization: OrganizationFormData = await this.fetchOrganizationById(this.$route.params.objId);

    (tab.model as OrganizationFormData) = organization;
    //todo сделать подгрузку applications
}
```

Во втором (наследуемом) я его переопределяю:

```
protected async mounted(): Promise<void> {
    this.modifyTabs();
}
```

Но в наследуемом компоненте выполняется mounted из первого компонента. Почему? Разве он не должен полностью замениться?

На всякий случай прикладываю скрин этих компонентов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас наследуется `Vue-комонент`, не просто класс. Это разные вещи. Во `Vue` сначала выполнится родительский `mounted`, а затем "`mounted` наследуемый". Т.е. по сути 2 разных компонента зарендерятся и каждый из них выполнит свой хук (даже если Вы его переопределили). Это такая фишка Vue. Можете обратить внимание на использование [миксинов](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) в данном случае. Переместите логику расширяемого и расширяющего компонентов. А в каждом компоненте используйте уже свой `mounted`.

Comment: Ок, поняла, спасибо!